# Centering the children of a div when number of children may vary

Tags: html, css

I've got a scenarion where I have a 940px width box, with up to 4 child divs of 140px, with 20px between them, floated in a line. I want the CSS to force the group of child divs to be centered, when there are 1, 2, 3, or 4 child divs. Currently, the position of the first 3 doesn't change when the 4th is removed.

I'm using LESS.

My code:

```
#parent
{
    position: relative;
    width: 940px;
    clear: both;
    background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

#parent h1
{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 5px;
    top: -24px;
}

#children
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.child
{
    width: 140px;
    padding-right:20px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;   
}

#children:last-child
{
    padding-right: 0px;
    clear: right;
}
```

EDIT: And the HTML...

```
<div id="parent">

    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

    <div id="children">

        <div class="child" id="1"></div>
        <div class="child" id="2"></div>
        <div class="child" id="3"></div>
        <div class="child" id="4"></div>

     </div>

 </div>
```

Also, the #children:last-child appears to be doing nothing. Am I right in assuming its rules should be being applied to #4?

Comment: And should we guess your HTML, or are you able to show us what you're working with?

Comment: How are you adding the div's. Are you adding these dynamically or are these being defined beforehand.. ??

Comment: You are using :last-child incorrectly. If you want to target child with id=4 you would use #children :last-child. because you want to target #children's child not the last child with ID #children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply set the width of div #children to 100% and text-align:center, so it's CSS becomes like this:

```
#children
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and for the children elements you have to remove the float property and give them a relative position:

```
.child
{
    width: 140px;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align: center;   
    position: relative;
}
```

It should works.
Also it's preferred if you specify the last child selector clearly by it's id, :last-child wont work on IE7 or IE6:

```
#4.child{
    padding-right: 0px;
    clear: right;
}
```

And I think you should not begin any id with number, id="1" | id="2" etc.. it is not correct in syntax.

Comment: He is using block level elements (Div) so this would work if he also adds:
display: inline-block;
to the child. Also you would want to reset the .child text-align to left if you don't want the content of the child to be centered within the child div too.

Comment: Yes it's true if he adds display: inline-block, but inline-block property is not supported in IE6, I've came through this same issue today where I have to set the display to inline.

Comment: You can use inline for the same results but the downside is if their heights are different it will be a staggered row. Although I don't think supporting IE6 is very common anymore. Not using display: inline; or inline-block; will simply not work since DIV is a block level element.

Comment: Yes IE6 support is not common anymore or not even cool, but that's what you have to do when the Q/A team in your company insist for this!
I hate IE6 by the way, but it's good practice to keep that stupid browser in mind while coding.

Comment: Point them to this site, owned by Microsoft: http://www.ie6countdown.com Unless you support users in China, IE6 has less than 1% usage in most countries.

Comment: No prob! Can't wait to see 0% world wide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle with it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/emYfz/

```
#children {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center    
}

.child {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 140px;
 height: 20px;
 margin: 5px;
 background: #f00;
}
```